# Bottling With Jelly Bean Question

Tags: bottling

I was reading about bottling home brew with jelly beans, Can I just buy the jelly beans at the grocery store or do I have to order them special for brewing?

Comment: What is the purpose of the jelly beans?  Is it to use as carbonation drops?

Comment: Maybe the jelly beans are for color?

Comment: I wouldn't think that jelly beans would dissolve fast enough to carb the beer in a reasonable amount of time.  Do you have a reference to this fantasy? I'd love to read more about it.

Comment: I come across this link https://www.howtohomebrewbeers.com/2016/06/how-to-make-jelly-bean-beer.html

Comment: This seems like an inexact way to add sugar for bottling.  Cute, but inexact. Seems like it would be too much sugar for a bottle.

Comment: the nutrition label shows the percentage of sugar in the bag. use some math and a weight scale to get the amount of sugar in each bean. if you know approximately how much sugar is in each bean, by weight, then you can just treat it like pure sugar based on that amount. but remember, the beans have preservatives that slow down fermentation and slowing the rate at which the yeast can penetrate the bean. the bean might have other stabilizers slowing the rate it dissolves, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grocery store. I've never seen any special homebrew jelly beans, and I've been at this for a long time.

When you add beans you're adding sugar (or possibly high fructose corn syrup), gelatin, fake coloring and fake flavoring to your beer. Just to make life more interesting, there are no standards for jelly bean size or sugar content, so I'm assuming it's pretty easy to under or over-carb your beer.

Or you could just use carbonation drops, which are way more predictable.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I was going to try them for carbonation, I do know never use the black ones.  I am interested in trying this method for  making  some flavor in the beer. To be safe I plan on only using orange, yellow and red ones for now. I am curious of the beer color, not  sure if using green ones and purple ones that could make a gross color.

Comment: Actually, the black ones might go very well in a beer like a stout or dubble.  As for the sugar content, you should be able to get a reasonable number off the nutritional information label; it is required to tell you how much sugar per serving is in the package.  For jelly beans, I'm pretty sure the serving size will say something like "about so-and-so jelly beans".

Comment: ive also had anise or licorice in some winter warmers, too, with a nice effect - like Nynashams mid winter ale. just a touch, tho.